# Query for additional properties?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Normally you would query like this

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Located in::Germany]] 
 |format=list
}}
```

How can you make the following work (as a List format)?

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Located in::Germany]] 
 [[Located in::England]]
 format=list
}}
```

For this it only puts out: Berlin

Goal is that it would put out: Berlin, London

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Located in::Germany||England]] 
 |format=list
}}
```

see:
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Unions_of_results

Comment: Thanks but I actually postet the wrong question. It was meant to say: ```{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Germany::]] 
 [[England::]]
| format=list
}}``` - that is what I am failing at